# how to pass parameters to redirected page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have script that work on button click:

```
 $scope.ShowDetailsAboutTicket = function (pinTicket) {
        if ($scope.showdetail == false && pinTicket != null) {
            $scope.pinTicket = pinTicket;


            $http.get(TicketUrl + 'GetTicket/' + $scope.terminalId + '/' + $scope.pinTicket)
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
                {

                    $("#background").addClass("darker");
                    $scope.showdetail = true;
                    $scope.ticketNotFound = false;
                    $location.search("ticketid", pinTicket);


                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                    $scope.ticketNotFound = true;
                    $scope.showdetail = false;



            })
           .then(TicketDetails, ErrorResponse);

        }

    }
```

Everything works fine.I get url :`http://localhost:60664/Home#?ticketid=8837278738` but i want when user click on button that redirect him to Sport page with those parameters...how can i do that? I tried with window.location but i dont get parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$routeParams` for this

Something like this:

```
Module.controller("yourControler", ["$routeParams", function($routeParams){
  //do whatever you need with the controller

 $scope.ticketId = $routeParams.ticketId;

 $scope.dosomethingOnSubmit = function() {
   //read $routeParams.ticketId and use $location to redirect user where you need to (but that will result in GET action)

  //Or you can perform your own POST request via $http service or $resource
  //Read the docs :)
 }
}]);
```

Then in your template you reference the ticketId

```
<a class="myButton" ng-href="some/path/?ticketId={{ticketId}}">Go to Sport page</a>
```

Ok, if that is submit button, then you can do this

```
<form ng-submit="dosomethingOnSubmit()">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

ngSubmit - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

$http - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

You should define routes in your configuration and then you should invoke that route when a user clicks your button.

You can use either [ng-route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or the more extended version [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).